# Extracting values from XML column in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: xml, plsql, xmltable

```sql
SELECT   x.xml_data.getClobVal()
FROM   test_xml x;
```

Results of above query is:

```
<CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
<GrpHdr>
<MsgId>191189    </MsgId>
</GrpHdr>
<PmtInf>
<PmtInfId>191189_65437    </PmtInfId>
<PmtMtd>EFT    </PmtMtd>
<NbOfTxs>2    </NbOfTxs>
<CtrlSum>3000.00    </CtrlSum>
<PmtTpInf>
<SvcLvl>
<Cd>NURG    </Cd>
</SvcLvl>
<LclInstrm>
<Cd>SDCL    </Cd>
</LclInstrm>
</PmtTpInf>
<PmtInf>
<PmtInfId>191189_65437    </PmtInfId>   
<RmtInf>
<Strd>
<RfrdDocInf>
<Tp>
<CdOrPrtry>
<Cd>CINV    </Cd>
</CdOrPrtry>
<Issr>Office Supplies    </Issr>
</Tp>
<Nb>3    </Nb>
<RltdDt>2022-01-24    </RltdDt>
</RfrdDocInf>
<RfrdDocAmt>
<DuePyblAmt Ccy="EUR">1000.00    </DuePyblAmt>
</RfrdDocAmt>
</Strd>
<Strd>
<RfrdDocInf>
<Tp>
<CdOrPrtry>
<Cd>CINV    </Cd>
</CdOrPrtry>
<Issr>Office Supplies    </Issr>
</Tp>
<Nb>4    </Nb>
<RltdDt>2022-01-24    </RltdDt>
</RfrdDocInf>
<RfrdDocAmt>
<DuePyblAmt Ccy="EUR">1000.00    </DuePyblAmt>
</RfrdDocAmt>
</Strd>
</RmtInf>
</PmtInf>
```

If I use:

```sql
select x.File_name, y.* 
from test_xml x, XMLTABLE('/CstmrCdtTrfInitn' passing  x.xml_data
COLUMNS  
--  CdtrInstrId PATH 'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/PmtId/InstrId'
--,CdtrNm PATH 'PmtInf/CdtrAcct/Nm2'
 StrdCd PATH 'PmtInf/RmtInf/Strd/RfrdDocInf/Tp/CdOrPrtry/Cd'
) y 
  where File_name = 2;
```

throws an error even though EXTRACTVALUE  is not used:

```
ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node
19025. 00000 -  "EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node"
*Cause:    Given XPath points to more than one node.
*Action:   Rewrite the query so that exactly one node is returned.
```

Need help to know how can I extract the values when there are repeating nodes such as tag Strd or tag RfrdDocInf etc. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't quite understood how `XMLTABLE` works.

An `XMLTABLE` expression takes the form

```sql
XMLTABLE('row_xpath' PASSING xml_source COLUMNS
  column1 datatype PATH 'col1_xpath',
  column2 datatype PATH 'col2_xpath'
  ...
)
```

Each matching result from the XPath expression `row_xpath` within `xml_source` corresponds to one row in the returned table. The XPath expressions `col1_xpath`, `col2_xpath` and so on contain the XPath expressions to select the values that make up each row from each element matching `row_xpath`.

In your `XMLTABLE`, your `row_xpath` is `'/CstmrCdtTrfInitn'`. This selects only the top-level element `CstmrCdtTrfInitn`, so your `XMLTABLE` will only ever return one row.

If we want our `XMLTABLE` to generate one row for each `Cd` element, then we need our `row_xpath` to select elements that only include one `Cd`. Looking at your document, we could select the `Strd` elements for this purpose, because each of the two `Strd` elements only contains one `Cd`. We can't use the `RmtInf` element for this purpose because it contains the two `Cd` elements. So, let's adjust the row-XPath to select the `Strd` elements and adjust the column-XPath to select the `Cd` element from within each `Strd` element:

```
SQL> select x.file_name, y.*
  2  from test_xml x,XMLTABLE('/CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/RmtInf/Strd' passing  x.xml_data
  3  COLUMNS
  4  --  CdtrInstrId PATH 'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/PmtId/InstrId'
  5  --,CdtrNm PATH 'PmtInf/CdtrAcct/Nm2'
  6   StrdCd VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH 'RfrdDocInf/Tp/CdOrPrtry/Cd'
  7   ) y
  8    where File_name = 2;

 FILE_NAME STRDCD
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         2 CINV
         2 CINV
```

You can then modify your `XMLTABLE` query to read further values out of your XML document and into other columns of the returned table. In the example below I read out the value of the `Nb` elements:

```
SQL> select x.file_name, y.*
  2  from test_xml x,XMLTABLE('/CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/RmtInf/Strd' passing  x.xml_data
  3  COLUMNS
  4  --  CdtrInstrId PATH 'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/PmtId/InstrId'
  5  --,CdtrNm PATH 'PmtInf/CdtrAcct/Nm2'
  6   StrdCd VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH 'RfrdDocInf/Tp/CdOrPrtry/Cd',
  7   StrdNb INTEGER PATH 'RfrdDocInf/Nb'
  8   ) y
  9    where File_name = 2;

 FILE_NAME STRDCD                                                 STRDNB
---------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------
         2 CINV                                                        3
         2 CINV                                                        4
```

---

Note also that in the last two examples I've specified the data-type of the value pulled out the XPath (`VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)` and `INTEGER`). In fact, if you modify your original `XMLTABLE` expression to add the column data-type in the same way, then you get a slightly more descriptive error:

```
SQL> select x.File_name, y.*
  2  from test_xml x, XMLTABLE('/CstmrCdtTrfInitn' passing  x.xml_data
  3  COLUMNS
  4  --  CdtrInstrId PATH 'PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/PmtId/InstrId'
  5  --,CdtrNm PATH 'PmtInf/CdtrAcct/Nm2'
  6   StrdCd VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH 'PmtInf/RmtInf/Strd/RfrdDocInf/Tp/CdOrPrtry/Cd'
  7  ) y
  8    where File_name = 2;
select x.File_name, y.*
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence
- got multi-item sequence
```

This tells you that you were expecting `StrdCd` to have a single value, but multiple elements matched the XPath expression `PmtInf/RmtInf/Strd/RfrdDocInf/Tp/CdOrPrtry/Cd`.

Comment: Thanks @Luke Woodward.  Is there a way I can select all the values in a single SQL without getting an error like this.

Comment: @DevadasWagle: not every element occurs multiple times in your XML, so how you would expect the resulting table to look if you were selecting 'all values'?